# Drag and drop into other program

Tags: python, pywin32

I would like to create an application for drag and drop to take a file into other application. For example, in my python window I would like take file and drop it in windows or photoshop. Is it possible in Python and need I use pywin32? For the moment I didn't find any information about this problem or just into window program path
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have Windows, but from what I remember, you'll need to have a window's handle (either for the shell Window or for some graphical one e.g. WinForms or others). Then try to check the [`WM_DROPFILES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/wm-dropfiles) message or better, [`ole2.h`'s `RegisterDragDrop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ole2/nf-ole2-registerdragdrop) and via [`pDropTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleidl/nn-oleidl-idroptarget) try to retrieve the sent path.

For `WM_DROPFILES` you can take an inspiration from SDL2's codebase in [`SDL_windowsevents.c`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/adf3ce7c01002456dc567cf9bdb20f9166b4fb2c/src/video/windows/SDL_windowsevents.c#L1386)

```c
    case WM_DROPFILES:
        {
            UINT i;
            HDROP drop = (HDROP) wParam;
            UINT count = DragQueryFile(drop, 0xFFFFFFFF, NULL, 0);
            for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                SDL_bool isstack;
                UINT size = DragQueryFile(drop, i, NULL, 0) + 1;
                LPTSTR buffer = SDL_small_alloc(TCHAR, size, &isstack);
                if (buffer) {
                    if (DragQueryFile(drop, i, buffer, size)) {
                        char *file = WIN_StringToUTF8(buffer);
                        SDL_SendDropFile(data->window, file);
                        SDL_free(file);
                    }
                    SDL_small_free(buffer, isstack);
                }
            }
            SDL_SendDropComplete(data->window);
            DragFinish(drop);
            return 0;
        }
        break;
```

which uses [`WIN_WindowProc()`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/adf3ce7c01002456dc567cf9bdb20f9166b4fb2c/src/video/windows/SDL_windowsevents.c#L650) in [this manner](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/adf3ce7c01002456dc567cf9bdb20f9166b4fb2c/src/video/windows/SDL_windowsevents.c#L1895):

Initialize [`WNDCLASSEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassexw) struct:

```c
WNDCLASSEX wcex;
// fill its members and this one for event handling:
wcex.lpfnWndProc = WIN_WindowProc;
```

then register it with [`RegisterClassEx(&wcex)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassexa).

Of course, that's just C/C++ code. You'll either need to find translated or otherwise linked members of the libraries in pywin32 or use something that can access the libraries in a way you need, such as [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) or [Cython](https://cython.org/).

Other resources:

- [Transferring Shell Objects with Drag-and-Drop and the Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/dragdrop)
- [Drag-and-Drop Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/drag-and-drop-overview#drag-and-drop-events)